org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class and content type [application/json]
This is my controller, what it does is trying to redirect to another api call,  I got
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class  and content type [application/json] 
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:118)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1134)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1117)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:867)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:765)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:676)

when trigger this endpoint, can anyone help on this? I can confirmed that the other api call is success, I can see the logs, but got error when trying to get the response.
      @RequestMapping(value = "/sellers/{seller}/taxes",
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> calculate(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders requestHeaders,
                                                        @PathVariable("seller") String seller,
                                                        @RequestBody Request request)
        throws Exception {

        HttpEntity<Request> entity = new HttpEntity<>(request, requestHeaders);
        ResponseEntity<CalculatedTaxes> response;
        try {
            response = getRestTemplate()
                    .exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<CalculatedTaxes>() {
                    });

            LOGGER.info("Received calculated tax: {}", response.getBody());
        }

}
protected RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    if (restTemplate != null) {
        return restTemplate;
    }
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().addAll(converters);
    return restTemplate;
}


Try add converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()); to handle JSON responses

You are using Spring Boot but try very hard to work around it. DItch your getRestTemplate() method. Inject the RestTEmplateBuilder into your controller (in the constructor) and call build() on that in the constructor to create a RestTemplate once for use. Or even better make it into an @Bean method and inject the RestTemplate into your controller. Also add the full stacktrace not just a snippet of it.
